# Quarkus runtime extension module

Tags: microservices, quarkus, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I've a question about how to add a plugin jar without build the whole project.
I mean, I'm developing a product that will be used, potentially, by different customers, it is possible that sume customer will required a customization.
In spring, for example, I can use an interface and I can ha a jar with the customization that implemets the interface, during the deployment phase I can add the custom jar in the classpath and all can work.

In quarkus, I understand, it is all managed during the compile phase, so I cant have a general product and a "plug and play" jar to add in the classpath.

How is the best practice to have a general application (ie: microservice) with the possibility to add a custom extension mechanism of the customer?

Thanks a lot to all
KR
Claudio

Comment: I've found a possible solution. Long story short, you can create a new project and add as dependency the principal project, you'll inherit all beans and configuration, so you can override them and add other implementation